# How can I load a Java applet from a dynamic server-side URL?

Tags: java, applet, cgi

I want to load an applet from a server side script, eg. a Perl CGI program, etc. Can this be done? how?

```
<applet code=A21 width=256 height=256 archive="http://url/cgi-bin/test.cgi?R=applet">
```

thanks in advance for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this is a long time (so the security model might have changed on me), but the trick was to configure the server to handle some translation. Say that you have the URL:

```
 http://example.com/applets/MyCode/1.0
```

You set up the URL translation such that you handle *http://example.com/applets* with your CGI script, which then gets */MyCode/1.0* as `PATH_INFO`. You return whatever you need to return.

Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able achived this. The mechanism I used was that the cgi script file was wrapped in a shell script. This wrapper calls the cgi script and it would then then embed the original url with a special request in the page it served as the applet. The script would then get run again and detect this special request. It would break without any output but with a return value that the shellscript would catch and output the jar/classfile.

Fetch.sh

```
run_the_cgi_script.cgi
```

case $? in

```
0) #normal script operation without special requests
   #do nothing more
;; 

1) #a special request that maps to Test3.class
echo "Content-type: application/java-archive"
echo ""
cat ./$myDIR/Test3.class;;

2) #a special request that maps to someclass.class
echo "Content-type: application/java-archive"
echo ""
cat ./$myDIR/someclass.class;;

3) #a special request that maps to somejar.jar
echo "Content-type: application/java-archive"
echo ""
cat ./$myDIR/somejar.jar;;
```

esac

Answer (score 0):

From [the doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html):

> For security reasons, the applet's
>   class loader can read only from the
>   same codebase from which the applet
>   was started. This means that archives
>   in archiveList must be in the same
>   directory as, or in a subdirectory of,
>   the codebase

so I suspect this will be problematic.